# Render Remote Component on Server Side Next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am attempting to build a React component library which can be independently deployed from the apps which use it. I'm doing this by loading the components over the network, and then rendering them in a Next.js app.  I know I can achieve this using [react-umd-loader](https://github.com/revolunet/react-umd-loader), but that only works client side because it relies on scriptjs. I was able to get this working using the vm npm package. This is what [my page](https://github.com/bernardwolff/ReactRemoteComponentSsr/blob/master/my-app/pages/index.js) in Next.js looks like.

```
const Index = (props) => {
  let sandbox = {'React': React, 'ReactDOM': ReactDOM, 'MyComponent': null, 'self': {}};
  vm.runInNewContext(props.MyComponent, sandbox);
  const MyComponent = sandbox.MyComponent.default;
  return (<div><p>Hello from Next.js</p><MyComponent /></div>)
}

Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/MyComponent.bundle.js')
  const script = await res.text()
  return { MyComponent: script }
}
```

MyComponent is a react component built with the following [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/bernardwolff/ReactRemoteComponentSsr/blob/master/my-component-library/webpack.config.js)

```
entry: {
    MyComponent: "./src/components/MyComponent",
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/static/js'),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    library: "[name]",
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    globalObject: 'this'
},
```

This actually works fine, but, I want [the component](https://github.com/bernardwolff/ReactRemoteComponentSsr/blob/master/my-component-library/src/components/MyComponent.jsx) to fetch data and then display that data, which is not working.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {data: {msg: 'data not loaded'}};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({data: json}))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
  render() {
      return (
      <div style={{border: '1px solid black'}}>
          <h1>My Component</h1>
          This data was fetched from an API:
          <pre>
              {JSON.stringify(this.state.data)}
          </pre>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

I think the reason this is not working is because the fetch is asynchronous, and the page is rendered and returned to the client before the fetch completes. I tried using [fetch-suspense](https://github.com/CharlesStover/fetch-suspense) but this did not work. I see `Promise { <pending> }` on the server console, so maybe the fetch promise just isn't completing?

Is it possible to make the server wait to respond until the fetch from the API has completed?

My full repo is at https://github.com/bernardwolff/ReactRemoteComponentSsr

Thanks!

Comment: ComponentDidMount is not called on server side,